# Attatching a P6 x 2 Managed Disk to my Azure VM Machine

Tags: azure

Upon following the instruction to created a data disk for my B1S UK South VM from the following source:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/attach-managed-disk-portal

The only option I get is to attached an unmanaged disk. There is no option to Create Managed Disk in Step 6. I'm wanting to mount two P6 64GB SSD disks in line with Azures Free Products.

The image below is the only screen I see when clicking Add Data Disk - no option to add a Managed (P6 SDD) disk anywhere.

[Click here to view the screen I see when Clicking "Add Data Disk"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce6pO.png)

Has anyone else had this issue and if so, how did they resolved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you created the VM using unmanaged disks and now the only option you have is to use this type of disk. If you want to use managed disks, you first need to convert the VM from unmanaged to managed disks. Follow this tutorial:

[Convert a Windows virtual machine from unmanaged disks to managed disks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/convert-unmanaged-to-managed-disks)

Comment: That's great, thank you. So how would i adjust the size of the disk in order to meet my budget requirements, bearing in mind that you cannot downsize a managed disk?

Comment: If you're using Premium disks, it doesn't matter if it's unmanaged or managed, you always pay for the entire disk. As you said, its not possible to downsize the disk, so make sure to deploy the correct size leaving a bit of room for growth. If in the future you realise your disk is too high for your needs, the only way to reduce the cost is to create a new disk and copy files over to the new one.

Comment: Also bear in mind that with managed disks both standard and premium follow the same pricing structure, you pay for the size of the disk attached, not the amount used.

Comment: I'm sorry but it makes me so angry that I'm wasting my time ripping my hair out just because whoever writes these documents doesn't bother to test their answers before they publish their instruction - they might as well instruct us to squeeze a bottle of ketchup over our head for the good it'll do in solving the issue.

Comment: What happened? Are you saying my instructions didn't work for you or the Microsoft article?